# Access 2007 - relationship view showing ghost tables

Tags: ms-access, table-relationships

When I pull in two tables in the relationship view window, 5 tables appear.  Three appear to be duplicates (patients, patients_1, patients_2).  I've cleared the window and started over - same problem.  In the side bar there is only one "patients" table.

How to I get rid of the duplicate 'ghost' tables? I can hide them, but this doesn't exactly get rid of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not ghost tables, these tables illustrate your relationships. There are a few reasons why you may need more that one image of the table to illustrate the relationship. For example, if there is a self-join on the table.